# CSS content: url() not working correctly with Firefox and Edge (even with ::before or ::after)

Tags: javascript, css, kendo-scheduler

I am overriding the recurrence symbol that Kendo Scheduler puts on events (an '!' with a circle around it) to be circling arrows with the following css:

```
.k-task>span.k-icon.k-i-warning {
        content: url('{!URLFOR($Asset.slds, "assets/icons/utility/sync.svg")}') !important;
        -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
        -moz-filter: invert(100%);
        -ms-filter: invert(100%);
        -o-filter: invert(100%);
    }
    .k-event>span.k-event-actions>span.k-icon.k-i-warning {
        content: url('{!URLFOR($Asset.slds, "assets/icons/utility/sync.svg")}') !important;
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-top: -5px;
    }
```

This works fine in Chrome, however, Firefox and Edge still show up as the circled '!'. I tried doing the ::after and ::before thing after each one and that didn't really work.

Doing ::before replaced the ! with the circling arrows, but the icon was enormous, and setting the width and height and font-size etc... did nothing to change the size of the icon.

Chrome simply swaps their default ! icon with the one I am specifying in content, so no other alterations with size is required.

How can I get this to show up correctly with Firefox and Edge?

Comment: Can you please include a [mcve]? It's hard to debug a fragment of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way

```
.k-task>span.k-icon.k-i-warning {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
    -moz-filter: invert(100%);
    -ms-filter: invert(100%);
    -o-filter: invert(100%);
}
.k-event>span.k-event-actions>span.k-icon.k-i-warning:after {        
    content: '';
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center center;
    background-image: url('{!URLFOR($Asset.slds, "assets/icons/utility/sync.svg")}') !important;
    margin-right: 10px; /*I am not sure why you need these*/
    margin-top: -5px;/*I am not sure why you need these*/
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, firefox seems to not recognize it at all unless :before is used. But even with background-image it gave the same kind of behavior. It blows up the icon, then will not allow it to be shrunk via font-size or width and height. All those do is adjust the element bounds and not the size of the actual icon.

Comment: Ah! I see. yes, `content` attribute will only come in place with :before, :after pseudo selectors. see my updated answer

Comment: With that update, when you change the size of main class, it should resize icon to fill main container

Comment: That worked perfect! Actually, using your background-size and background-position attributes, my margins are not needed anymore and actually bump it out of view. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (assuming you have control of the HTML): add an empty right after the input, and target that in CSS using input+ span:after

```
.field_with_errors {
  display: inline;
  color: red;
}
.field_with_errors input+span:after {
  content: "*"
}
<div class="field_with_errors">Label:</div>
<div class="field_with_errors">
  <input type="text" /><span></span> 
</div>
```

I'm using this approach in AngularJS because it will add .ng-invalid classes automatically to form elements, and to the form, but not to the .